# Output the first several keys of Java map

Tags: java, iteration, keyset

I want to print out the first several keys (not the values, not all the keys) of a Java map. E.g., how to output the first 10 keys?

Comment: You cannot sort a HashMap, your question is unclear. You can get the keys by using keySet(), then order them, then iterate over the first 10 ones and return them.

Comment: You cannot sort a HashMap, and you cannot sort a TreeMap by value; as such your question does not make sense.

Comment: I know I cannot sort a HashMap, and I am not asking how to sort a HashMap. Sorry for the confusion. Hope I can get my reputation votes back.

Comment: The point of the above comments is that there's not really any notion for HashMap of which keys are "first," since they can be in any order and that order can change.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 :

```
map.keySet().stream().limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` sorted by value does not exist. `HashMap` is not sorted, and `TreeMap` is sorted by key only.

With Java 8 you can use a `Stream` for what you want:

```
map.entrySet().stream().sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```